# Qt Quick PinchHandler scale bounds don't work

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I try to use `PinchHandler` in QtQuick 2.15 (macOS). But properties `minimumScale` and `maximumScale` doesn't work properly. The target's Item scale is going out of bounds back time.

Any ideas how to make it work?
Here's code sample:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
    Rectangle{
        color: "blue"
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle{
            x: 10
            y: 10
            height: 10
            width: 10
            PinchHandler{
                minimumScale: 0.5
                maximumScale: 2

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a platform bug. You'd need to output the scale to a text item to monitor it, as a reproducer.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, I've done it. Looks like bug, qml doesn't care about bounds here. It works by using the old PinchArea. But while using happens another problem with pinch point (scale origin point), it's always in Item's center.